MapBox not working in qgis2web Plugin
I've imported customized basemap from Mapbox studio, and want to create a webpage for visualization  using qgis2web plugin.
The QGIS imports and displays the base map from map box properly.
However, when I try to create webpage using the qgis2web plugin it isn't showing the one imported from Map box, nor is the "Mapbox GL JS" getting highlited for me to select. It imports other base maps but not from Mapbox. I have attached the screen shot of same.
Any solution please?


The Mapbox GL JS export was removed a while ago as it was no longer supported. I will remove the writing to avoid any misunderstanding.
You can still insert your WMS or XYZ base maps and export the project with openlayers and leaflets. A guide here https://qgis2web.github.io/qgis2web/#setBasemaps

Hi, thank you for the response. I can import it as WMS base map. However, when I try to export it using qgis2web, the web map imported as WMS layer via mapbox doesn't show.  Any solutions for that pelase?

Can you create a zip from your QGIS project or your export and upload it to the web and link it here?

I have uploaded it to my Gdrive, the line and point are test layers. The "Outdoors" base map is obtained from Mapbox, which doesn't export in the plugin.                  Here is the link.  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1XQoivg56mbfh7h3bH9eD4_HSDFFILco8?usp=drive_link
It contains the project file as well.  Thank you

Export with openlayers then reach the layers.js file contained in the layers folder, modify your layer by adding tileLoadFunction: customLoader and add the customLoader function at the beginning of the file in which you will have to enter your username and password
function customLoader(tile, src) {
        var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
        client.open('GET', src);
        // Uncomment to pass authentication header
        //var user = '';
        //var pass = '';
        //client.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + window.btoa(user + ":" + pass));
        client.onload = function() {
          tile.getImage().src = src;
        };
        client.send();
      }

    var lyr_Outdoors_0 = new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.WMTS(({
            url: "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/adarshredhill/clyocmzb9004h01pidczp9caf/wmts",
            attributions: ' ',
            tileLoadFunction: customLoader,
            "layer": "clyocmzb9004h01pidczp9caf",
            "TILED": "true",
            matrixSet: 'EPSG:3857',
            format: 'image/png',
            projection: projection_Outdoors_0,
            tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.WMTS({
                origin: ol.extent.getTopLeft(projectionExtent_Outdoors_0),
                resolutions: resolutions_Outdoors_0,
                matrixIds: matrixIds_Outdoors_0
            }),
            style: 'default',
            wrapX: true,
            "VERSION": "1.0.0",
        })),
        title: "Outdoors",
        opacity: 1.0,
    
    
    });

